# How can I get DB records from table with time frame attributes?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I would like to ask for help with following issue:

I have a Ruby on Rails app with PostgreSQL.
I have there table `EVENTS`. Each event has 2 attributes
`starts_at` and `ends_at`. Which represents the time frame of duration of the event.

It might happened I'll have few events which happends at the same time.

I would like to construct queries where:

- I get all events that take place at given time frame. eg. "Give me all events from Dec.". If there is event that starts at Nov. and ends at Jan. I would like to get it too.
- I would like to get all events from given timestamp. Similar to the previous one, but as an input I just give timestamp instead of time frame.

My question is how should I start with solving the problem I described above?

Comment: Hello michal, next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

First get all events from a time frame.
Create a function and recive the parameters

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE ends_at  >= @your_begin_timeframe
AND   start_at <= @your_end_timeframe
```

If you want the events form a month you need a `months` table.

Months:

```
month_id  month_name  begin        end
   1      nov 2015    01/11/2015   30/11/2015
   2      dec 2015    01/12/2015   31/12/2015
```

Then join both tables

```
SELECT e.*, m.month_name
FROM events e
INNER JOIN months m
   ON e.ends_at   >= m.begin
  AND e.starts_at <= m.end
```